# Error on Insert SqlCommand in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm going crazy here, can someone please tell me what's wrong with this code

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO COUNTERS(COUNTER_START, COUNTER_CURRENT, COUNTER_NEXT, COUNTER_TYPE, COUNTER_DATE_CREATED, COUNTER_TIME_CREATED, COUNTER_CREATED_BY) " +
                    "VALUES(@counter_start, @counter_current, @counter_next, @counter_type, @date, @time, @user)", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@counter_start", SqlDbType.Int).Value = counter_start.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@counter_current", SqlDbType.Int).Value = counter_current.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@counter_next", SqlDbType.Int).Value = counter_next.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@counter_type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = counter_type.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = date;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = time;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = user;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
con.Close();
```

I'm getting this error

> The parameterized query '(@counter_start int,@counter_current int,@counter_next int,@coun' expects the parameter '@user', which was
>   not supplied

Any input will be really appreciate it.

Comment: You need a try/finally for your Dispose() call, or you can end up leaving connections hanging open.

Comment: Thank you. I do have them I just included the piece of code I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try debugging the application and see what value is being held by variable `user`. I think the `user` you are supplying is null. If you are using C# 4.0 then try

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = user ?? DBNull.Value;
```

or for earlier versions of C#

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = user != null ? user : DBNull.Value;
```

You may also use `string.Empty` in place of `DBNull.Value`, if you want an empty string instead of `DBNull`

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been writing code all day. I think is time for me to stop for the day. I spent the last 45 minutes trying to figure this out.